# codeigniter - how to generate a thumbnail image for video files

Tags: codeigniter, thumbnails

Hi..

I am working in codeigniter. I had facing problem in creating thumbnail image for video files.if any can give me the code for generating a thumbnail image for the video files using codeigniter. 
I had generated a thumbnail image for the image  using the below code

```
$config_manip = array(
'image_library' => 'gd2',
'source_image'  => "uploads/image_gallary/".$img,
'new_image'     => "uploads/image_gallary/thumbnails/thumb_".$img,
'maintain_ratio'=> TRUE ,
//'create_thumb'  => TRUE ,
'thumb_marker'  => '_thumb',
'width'         => 100,
'height'        => 100 
);
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

above coding doesn't working properly.let me explain how to create thumbnail image for video files.please guide me.

Comment: Does your server have ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 1):

to generate video thumbnail you can use the below

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i ".$video_url."  -y -an -sameq -f image2 -s 400x270 path/of/thumb/mythumb.jpg");
```

you may change the parameters for your needs

Comment: That assumes he has ffmpeg installed and access to the shell (via PHP). Both is really rare on shared hosting...

Comment: you can use exec instead 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
and ffmpeg is installed on most of the shared hosting servers